# Visualizing third variable with MatplotLib Histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-science

Excuse my bad english.

On a DataFrame like the following one :

```
-----------------
|index|var1|var2|
-----------------
```

there is lot of rows
var1 is between 0 and 4000
var2 is between -100 and 100

I'm looking to create an histogram that show how many rows there is according to var1.

[image]

On the Y axis, we can see how many rows there is, for example for 0 > var1 < 500, there is almost 500k rows.

Now I want to add var2, which show the quality of a row.
I want that for example the histgram become blue from 0 to 500 and another color from 500 to 1000 according to the value of var2 (like if the bar as values where the mean of var2 is 100, make it green, if the mean is 0, make it red).

I tried to hardcore this, but as soon as I change the bins or anything, my code break.

I also tried to do it using plot on the top of the hist, but it doesn't work.

My current code for the screenshot :

```
plt.hist(var1, bins=10, range=(0,4000), color='orange', alpha=0.7)
plt.title('Var 1',weight='bold', fontsize=18)
plt.yticks(weight='bold')
plt.xticks(weight='bold')
```

I feel like this is simple things to do, but I'm completely stuck in my learning because of this.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a list containing the colors for each bar in your histogram you can use the following code snippet. It catches the return values of the `plt.hist` command, which include the individual patches. The color can be set individually while iterating through those patches.

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(var1, bins=8, range=(0,4000), color="orange", alpha=0.7)
for i, patch in enumerate(patches):
    plt.setp(patch, "facecolor", colors[i])
```

Additionally, here is one possible way to create the mentioned `color list` based on the kind of data you have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create random values and store them in a DataFrame
y1 = np.random.randint(0,4000, 50)
y2 = np.random.randint(-100, 101, 50)
y = zip(y1,y2)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=["Var1","Var2"])

var1 = df["Var1"].values

# pd.cut to bin the dataframe in the appropriate ranges of Var1
# then the mean of Var2 is calculated for each bin, results are stored in a list
mean = [df.groupby(pd.cut(df["Var1"], np.arange(0, 4000+500, 500)))["Var2"].mean()]

# how to color the bars based on Var2:
# -100 <= mean(Var2) < -33: blue
# -33 <= mean(Var2) < 33: red
# 33 <= mean(Var2) < 100: green
color_bins = np.array([-100,-33,33,100])
color_list = ["blue","red","green"]

# bin the means of Var2 according to the color_bins we just created
inds = np.digitize(mean, color_bins)

# list that assigns the appropriate color to each patch
colors = [color_list[value-1] for value in inds[0]]

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(var1, bins=8, range=(0,4000), color="orange", alpha=0.7)
for i, patch in enumerate(patches):
    plt.setp(patch, "facecolor", colors[i])

plt.title('Var 1',weight='bold', fontsize=18)
plt.yticks(weight='bold')
plt.xticks(weight='bold')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Not only your code is perfect, but also I understood everything because of your comments. This is the best answer I have ever received on stackoverflow !! Thank you !!